# how to set gravity in jetpack compose Text

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I have a text component that height is 48dp and want to set the text center in vertical.

Like the TextView with 48dp height and gravity is center_vertical.

Or I have to put it(Text compose) in Surface component?

Comment: What you ask is not possible only with `Text`. You can use a Box with 48.dp and set Box property `contentAlignment =Alignment.Center` which is counterpart of  `android:layout_gravity`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is correct, you would need to put it in a box for instance, or a column, and center it that way.

```
    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize, contentAlignment = Alignment.Center){
    Text(text = "My Text") }
```